# wrapper around createAsyncThunk has odd type inference issues

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I have an action creator created using `createAsyncThunk`, provided by `@reduxjs/toolkit`:

```
const login = createAsyncThunk<
  {},
  { email: string; password: string},
  { rejectValue: { message: string; field?: string }[] }
>(
  'auth/login',
  async (payload: { email: string; password: string }, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      return await loginAPI(payload);
    } catch (error: any) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);
```

The action creator works perfectly well, but I want to extract common code which will be repeated in all of my action creators.

So, I have created a wrapper around `createAsyncThunk` function:

```
import {
  AsyncThunkPayloadCreator,
  createAsyncThunk,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

type AsyncThunkConfig = {
  rejectValue?: { message: string; field?: string }[];
};

const createAppAsyncThunk = <
  Returned,
  ThunkArg = void,
  ThunkApiConfig extends AsyncThunkConfig = {}
>(
  typePrefix: string,
  callback: AsyncThunkPayloadCreator<Returned, ThunkArg, ThunkApiConfig>
) => {
  const typedCreateAsyncThunk = createAsyncThunk.withTypes<Required<AsyncThunkConfig>>();
  return typedCreateAsyncThunk(typePrefix, async (payload: ThunkArg, thunkApi) => {
  //                                                                 ^^^^^^^^ I see error here
    try {
      return await callback(payload, thunkApi);
    } catch (error: any) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  });
};
```

The wrapper has a bit odd behavior.

### Scenario 1:

In the current state of the code, I see a red squiggly line under callback function's `thunkApi` parameter as seen in my code. Also, you can check it in [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwFBzgQQM4E8B2BjAFQAsBXHAawAUBDLAGwmoBMBhKAU2pmgBoU48HLu0y5CpCn1SDOMdgGU6wPOz4BfOADMoEEHADkAAQ5MSADwBWGAPTcIdcsBj6A3EiQwsYdumz5iZOQsEDiawADmcAC8iPwcFux4MABq1HQk7AD8AFyIcCDsGBjU4ey5GDBQwDjhLlrA7HRMOXAVVTVwagDaALpuam5IeCEVAkJyaGBgov4S5NFwADz8AErsMCRQOOxMUnABFGhQkTEAbhDAu-wH5JPAwaERcOxmcjhMGL5iNw9hJ4hqJAAPgAFPxPN5KBwwmZypVquE9ng0nQAEbUPDkXIzcSBGj0RiscbQRZrDZbHY8fZzI6I6mBO6-CJApAASmiQNi0hG8AhOzYshEflxFAWMmEOJuADoAO5OIgELyFUnsACOJGAJkWkrmTPCQNBrLcqA45JwcD5RMFOsCIL5UPYMKp1GFcBBYFoDGYuRutKpMBpYGA7KinOQqFQlSwXIjJvWm3N1Bl1CcAhR6Mx7s9hP9geDxojGmRMDwRDd7CgOiguWoOCw7PDsbgpoTFrzUviiRgAHV5al0uwQRWq0b%20KhAePRwN3MMcKMGOFqmhKABJBZZgnevLsEApuhw9q1OAeooy6BMA8IupqENhuLxrZwbYyuBQ3TADCDkGdpK31rrAhQHYCASBgEEQT-H8wK6BB8kKYpSlyfQAFFd2AOg4GgY8XQwM8oCYOAP0I-BoA4JIpX0KkwkaC8DB3Pd9E6HpWSpABWAAGdjWSnGceTgBdqjFcYRCmG0KDBVB9GoUCiGsAScEo-gXTEN0PU3WjYPo9DLxqOoT1w88dMiNRcwZIM-0bOMzTgJMU3geTlxXDcvSYUdxzZQZZ1GaSA0UZQfBicU5D8lQQUbHBqAKJCfKIRTUGqJxgDSeQYGEXIEBM%209TBUKAMHSzLUBeSpqDWbKKzyt1UQ1JoKwssc4Gsaw4ClFrWl0HxhiYHwiArdh6qq9CuqgKVmFYF1B3kjt2ASJJKTdCphGdJJgBCOqmwapruTnex2ClBcQX0eStD3HZ9DcpsvJ2vaIHCEEMRgFacClNSXKpfQDQNGzlpCM6C0nAtMpvNwgA)

The exact error message is:

```
Argument of type 'GetThunkAPI<{ state: unknown; dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>; extra: unknown; rejectValue: { message: string; field?: string | undefined; }[]; serializedErrorType: unknown; pendingMeta: unknown; fulfilledMeta: unknown; rejectedMeta: unknown; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GetThunkAPI<ThunkApiConfig>'.
  Type '{ state: unknown; dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>; extra: unknown; rejectValue: { message: string; field?: string | undefined; }[]; serializedErrorType: unknown; pendingMeta: unknown; fulfilledMeta: unknown; rejectedMeta: unknown; }' is not assignable to type 'ThunkApiConfig'.
    '{ state: unknown; dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>; extra: unknown; rejectValue: { message: string; field?: string | undefined; }[]; serializedErrorType: unknown; pendingMeta: unknown; fulfilledMeta: unknown; rejectedMeta: unknown; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'ThunkApiConfig', but 'ThunkApiConfig' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'AsyncThunkConfig'.ts(2345)
```

But types in the code, that uses this code, seems to work fine.

### Scenario 2:

If I remove usage of `Required` utility helper, then I don't get any errors, but type inference breaks.

This line of code (from above wrapper, does not infer correct types for `rejectWithValue`, which inturn breaks type inference for everything that uses this wrapper):

```
return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
```

This is how you should call the wrapper function `createAppAsyncThunk`:

```
const loginAPI = (payload: { email: string; password: string; }) => {
  return new Promise((reject) => setTimeout(() => reject([{ message: 'Email or password is incorrect.', field: 'email' }]), 500));
}

export const login = createAppAsyncThunk(
  'auth/login',
  async (payload: { email: string; password: string }, thunkApi) => {
    return await loginAPI(payload);
  }
);
```

And in reducer created using `createSlice`, you can test the type inference of `action.payload` inside `login.rejected` case:

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    // ... some code here
    builder.addCase(login.rejected, (state, action) => {
      //   console.log('login failed');
      console.log(action.payload, '>>>> action');
    });
  },
});
```

You can hover over `action.payload` and you should see this type, if inference works correctly:

```
payload: {
    message: string;
    field?: string | undefined;
}[] | undefined
```

Incase, if it fails to infer, you should see:

```
payload: unknown
```

I am able to reproduce this issue on [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwFBzgQQM4E8B2BjAFQAsBXHAawAUBDLAGwmoBMBhKAU2pmgBoU48HLu0y5CpCn1SDOMdgGU6wPOz4BfOADMoEEHADkAAQ5MSADwBWGAPTcIdcsBj6A3EiQwsYdumz5iZOQsEDiawADmcAC8iPwcFux4MABq1HQk7AD8AFyIcCDsGBjU4ey5GDBQwDjhLlrA7HRMOXAVVTVwagDaALpuam5IeCEVAkJyaGBgov4S5NFwADz8AErsMCRQOOxMUnABFGhQkTEAbhDAu-wH5JPAwaERcOxmcjhMGL5iNw9hJ4hqJAAPgAFPxPN5KBwwmZypVquE9ng0nQAEbUPDkXIzcSBGj0RiscbQRZrDZbHY8fZzI6I6mBO6-CJApAASmiQNi0hG8AhOzYshEflxFAWMmEOJuADoAO5OIgELyFUnsACOJGAJkWkrmTPCQNBrLcqA45JwcD5RMFOsCIL5UPYMKp1GFcBBYFoDGYuRutKpMBpYGA7KinOQqFQlSwXIjJvWm3N1Bl1CcAhR6Mx7s9hP9geDxojGmRMDwRDd7CgOiguWoOCw7PDsbgpoTFrzUviiRgAHV5al0uwQRWq0b%20KhAePRwN3MMcKMGOFqmhKABJBZZgnevLsEApuhw9q1OAeooy6BMA8IupqENhuLxrZwbYyuBQ3TADCDkGdpK31rrAhQHYCASBgEEQT-H8wK6BB8kKYpSlyfQAFFd2AOg4GgY8XQwM8oCYOAP0I-BoA4JIpX0KkwkaC8DB3Pd9E6HpWSpABWAAGdjWSnGceTgBdqjFcYRCmG0KDBVB9GoUCiGsAScEo-gXTEN0PU3WjYPo9DLxqOoT1w88dMiNRcwZIM-0bOMzTgJMU3geTlxXDcvSYUdxzZQZZ1GaSA0UZQfBicU5D8lQQUbHBqAKJCfKIRTUGqJxgDSeQYGEXIEBM%209TBUKAMHSzLUBeSpqDWbKKzyt1UQ1JoKwssc4Gsaw4ClFrWl0HxhiYHwiArdh6qq9CuqgKVmFYF1B3kjt2ASJJKTdCphGdJJgBCOqmwapruTnex2ClBcQX0eStD3HZ9DcpsvJ2vaIHCEEMRgFacClNSXKpfQDQNGzlpCM6C0nAtMpvNwgA)